# json.dumps vs flask.jsonify

Tags: python, json, flask

I am not sure I understand the purpose of the `flask.jsonify` method. I try to make a JSON string from this:

```
data = {"id": str(album.id), "title": album.title}
```

but what I get with `json.dumps` differs from what I get with `flask.jsonify`.

```
json.dumps(data): [{"id": "4ea856fd6506ae0db42702dd", "title": "Business"}]
flask.jsonify(data): {"id":…, "title":…}
```

Obviously I need to get a result that looks more like what `json.dumps` returns. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 446, accepted):

The `jsonify()` function in flask returns a `flask.Response()` object that already has the appropriate content-type header 'application/json' for use with json responses. Whereas, the `json.dumps()` method will just return an encoded string, which would require manually adding the MIME type header.

See more about the `jsonify()` function [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.json.jsonify) for full reference.

Edit:
Also, I've noticed that `jsonify()` handles kwargs or dictionaries, while `json.dumps()` additionally supports lists and others.

Comment: `jsonify()` handles lists now. See [this commit](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/commit/431db2874b242316051963d9bc4d5653b3647acc).

Comment: But it still does not turn SQLAlchemy objects and lists into JSON.

Comment: I used jsonify to send json to the client. While for smaller dictionaries, the response works fine, for large arrays I get a content length mismatched error on the browser. Any ideas as to why this happens? there's a limit to how much data I can send?

Comment: Also, from my test, jsonify handles python's set objects

Answer (score 98):

You can do:

```
flask.jsonify(**data)
```

or

```
flask.jsonify(id=str(album.id), title=album.title)
```

Answer (score 91):

This is `flask.jsonify()`

```
def jsonify(*args, **kwargs):
    if __debug__:
        _assert_have_json()
    return current_app.response_class(json.dumps(dict(*args, **kwargs),
        indent=None if request.is_xhr else 2), mimetype='application/json')
```

The `json` module used is either `simplejson` or `json` in that order. `current_app` is a reference to the `Flask()` object i.e. your application. `response_class()` is a reference to the `Response()` class.

Comment: This is the best answer so far. I think Jsonify is a good shorthand for when no customization of real import is required

Answer (score 53):

The choice of one or another depends on what you intend to do. 
From what I do understand:

- **jsonify** would be useful when you are building an API someone would query and expect json in return. E.g: The REST github API could use this method to answer your request.
- **dumps**, is more about formating data/python object into json and work on it inside your application. For instance, I need to pass an object to my representation layer where some javascript will display graph. You'll feed javascript with the Json generated by dumps.

Comment: I don't understand the difference at all.

Comment: @vidstige: **jsonify** makes a flask.Response() object with its headers set as "content-type: application/json", its payload set as the converted-to-JSON-string dict. **dumps** simply makes a converted-to-JSON-string. It's not a properly-formatted flask.Response() object. So if your view says "return json.dumps(dict)", then the recipient will just get a regular "content-type:text/html" response with the json.dumps output as the payload.

Comment: @SamEsla yes, I know, but none of that information is in this answer.

Answer (score -2):

consider

```
data={'fld':'hello'}
```

now

```
jsonify(data)
```

will yield {'fld':'hello'} and

```
json.dumps(data)
```

gives

```
"<html><body><p>{'fld':'hello'}</p></body></html>"
```

Comment: if we are speaking about Python, then no, outputs are not like you described