# jsonify/pretty-print JSON for Bottle

Tags: python, json, bottle, pretty-print

I'm making a JSON-output API in Bottle, and I would like to pretty-print the JSON. Right now  if I write `return json.dumps(data, indent=4, default=json_util.default)`, it still prints it without indents or newlines into my browser (but it does print correctly into my terminal).

My question is basically the Bottle version of this:
[Flask Display Json in a Neat Way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908943/flask-display-json-in-a-neat-way)

But I can't use the answer because (as far as I can tell) there is no `jsonify` function in Bottle. Is there an obvious solution, or should I try to reverse-engineer Flask's `jsonify`?

Comment: Your browser propably interprets the text as HTML by default, which doesn't print `\n` and ommits consecutive spaces. Either wrap your JSON in `<pre>` or set the Content-Type to `application/json`

Comment: Yep, setting `response.content_type` is the way to go here

Comment: Aww man, see I knew it was obvious / inappropriate to procrastinate on manually setting the content-type. Thanks! If someone migrates to an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Felk comment:
set `resopnse.content_type`to `application/json`.

```
def result():
    response.content_type='application/json'
    return data
```

or

```
def result():
    return '<pre>{}</pre>'.format(json.dumps(data, 
            indent=4, default=json_util.default))
```

both will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I created the [bottle-json-pretty](https://pypi.org/project/bottle-json-pretty/) plugin to extend the existing JSON dump done by Bottle.

I like being able to use the dictionary returned by my Bottle JSON/API functions in other template/view functions that return an actual page. Calling `json.dumps` or making a wrapper broke this since they would return the dumped `str` instead of a `dict`.

Example using bottle-json-pretty:

```py
from bottle import Bottle
from bottle_json_pretty import JSONPrettyPlugin

app = Bottle(autojson=False)
app.install(JSONPrettyPlugin(indent=2, pretty_production=True))

@app.get('/')
def bottle_api_test():
    return {
        'status': 'ok',
        'code': 200,
        'messages': [],
        'result': {
            'test': {
                'working': True
            }
        }
    }

# You can now have pretty formatted JSON
# and still use the dict in a template/view function

# @app.get('/page')
# @view('index')
# def bottle_index():
#     return bottle_api_test()

app.run()
```