# How to correctly use Flask's jsonify() to return json?

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm having a little trouble using the flask.jsonify function to output a formatted json response from a dictionary input, as described in [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908943/flask-display-json-in-a-neat-way)

My code is seems to be returning the Response object, instead of the formatted json object that I want.

I have

```
@app.route('/rparser', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def rparser():
    form = ParserForm(request.form)
    if request.method=='POST':
        result = jsonify(**dict)
        return render_template('rparser.html', form=form, result=result)
    else:
        return render_template('rparser.html', form=form)
```

where dict is a dictionary object returned from calling a function.

And in my template, I have:

```
(form up here)

{% if result %}
    {{ result }}
{% endif %}
```

This is displaying:

> Response 135 bytes [200 OK]

How would I make this return the json representation that I am looking for?

Comment: What is wrong with `json.dumps`?

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm looking to display the json pretty-printed, which json.dumps doesn't do

Comment: What is `dict` here? Where is the JSON data supposed to be coming from?

Comment: According to the flask api, jsonify does return a Response object, which the the string you are seeing. You can do `return jsonify(...)` if the JSON is all you want to see.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The dict is an OrderedDict compiled by calling another function, which takes in arguments from a form on the same page. Here is an example of the dictionary:



OrderedDict([('name', 'Example'), ('reference_ranges', [OrderedDict([('descriptions', ['Follicular']), ('ranges', [OrderedDict([('min', 22.0), ('max', 85.0), ('units', 'ng/dL ')]), OrderedDict([('tag', 'SI'), ('min', 0.7), ('max', 2.5), ('units', 'mmol/L')])])])])])

Comment: @cricket_007 Is it possible for me to implement this so that the JSON appears on the rendered template, instead of being returned directly? I currently have it adjacent to a form that generates it and I want to keep it that way. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if they can be rendered together. I'm on a phone, so can't really test anything. You may want to browse through the documentation for something that catches your eye. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#module-flask.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use json.dumps like so:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
return render_template(
    'index.html',
    title='Home Page',
    result=json.dumps({"a":[{"o":1},{"o":2}]}, sort_keys = False, indent = 2)
)
```

and just format it in the template like so:

```
{% if result %}
   <pre>{{ result }}</pre>
{% endif %}
```

If this fits to your expectations. I think that jsonify is used to provide http.response data, not context data for templates.

Have a look here for jsonify: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13172658/1307985

Comment: The goal is to have the json be pretty-printed. How would I go about that, with json.dumps?

Comment: I have updated my answer. This should give you some kind of pretty printed json in the template, but not colored of course. You can change the indent to get more or less indention.

Comment: To have it colored there are many JavaScript libraries that will help.