# return utf8 json type in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm creating a RSS reader app in Flask. In my program I fetch feed data by `feedparser` package and I want to return data in JSON format.
My code works fine in English sites but when I want to fetch none English feeds I get the following error :

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)`

```
@app.route('/fetch',methods=['POST'])
def fetch():
    url = request.form['url']
    feed = feedparser.parse(url)
    output = {'response':'','result':''}
    body = ''
    for post in feed.entries:
        body += '<div class="post">'
        body += '<h3 class="post-title">{}</h3>'.format(post.title)
        body += '<div class="post-body">{}</div>'.format(post.summary_detail.value)
        body += '</div>'

    output['response'] = 'ok'
    output['result'] =   body  
    return json.dumps(output, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
```

I tried this :

```
    output['result'] =   body.encode('utf8')  
    return json.dumps(output, ensure_ascii=False)
```

but I have the same issue.

Comment: Please provide the *full traceback*. Are you sure it is not the `body +=` lines that throw the exception?

Comment: Note: [I'd suggest use `flask.jsonify()` instead of `json.dumps()`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907596/json-dumps-vs-flask-jsonify)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are interpolating Unicode strings into byte strings:

```
body += '<h3 class="post-title">{}</h3>'.format(post.title)
body += '<div class="post-body">{}</div>'.format(post.summary_detail.value)
```

Both `post.title` and `post.summary_detail.value` need to be encoded to bytes for that to work, and Python uses `ASCII` for that. That's why you get an *encoding* error here.

Create a Unicode string instead:

```
body = []
for post in feed.entries:
    body.append(
        u'<div class="post">'
        u'<h3 class="post-title">{}</h3>'
        u'<div class="post-body">{}</div>'
        u'</div>'.format(post.title, post.summary_detail.value)
 body = u''.join(body)
```

The above uses `str.join()` to concatenate your divs, rather than create many small strings.