# Pretty Display JSON data from with Flask

Tags: python, json, flask

I've got a response object as a result of a `GET` request and I've converted this to `JSON` with `jsonify()`. When I pass this to a template, all I get is a JSON object like: `<Response 1366 bytes [200 OK]>` this.

```
#request.py
...
response = requests.get('http://www.example.com')
response_json = jsonify(all=response.text)

return render_template(
    'results.html',
    form=ReqForm(request.form),
    response=response_json,
    date=datetime.datetime.now()
)
```

and the template..

```
#results.html
...
<div class="results">
    {{ response }} # --> gives <Response 1366 bytes [200 OK]>
</div>
...
```

How can I pretty display this JSON in a template?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `json.dumps`

```
response = json.dumps(response.text, sort_keys = False, indent = 2)
```

or to make it prettier

```
response = json.dumps(response.text, sort_keys = True, indent = 4, separators = (',', ': '))
```

Template

```
#results.html
...
<div class="results">
    <pre>{{ response }}</pre>
</div>
...
```

The `jsonify()` function in flask returns `flask.Response()` object that already has the appropriate content-type header `'application/json'` for use with json responses, whereas the `json.dumps()` will just return an encoded string, which would require manually adding the mime type header.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13172658/264802

Comment: I feel like we are on the right path. I did `response = json.dumps(response.text, sort_keys=False, indent=2)` but the whole json got displayed as block. no newline or indentation.
`response = json.dumps(response_json, sort_keys=False, indent=2)` returns `<Response 1366 bytes [200 OK]> is not JSON serializable`

Comment: It's still displaying as a block of text. Take a look at it: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyMOXJ

Comment: Also see the updated <pre></pre> tag in the template for proper formatting.

Comment: That `<pre></pre>` tag will help as soon as I replace those `\"` with `"` and get rid of the `"` from the start and the end

Comment: Ok I did the above but with the `</pre>` tags it displays as 1 liner, without it it a block text again...

Comment: Look at setting the proper 'application/json' MIME type.

Comment: `render_template(...), {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}` makes the whole page in JSON format which is not what we want.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're after then? Consider accepting the answer, since it does fix your `<Response 1366 bytes [200 OK]>` question  and perhaps ask a different question?

Comment: Ok, I'll do that but just to clarify; I'm trying to display this JSON on page with indents etc.. (imagine in a box)  while there is other content around it.

Comment: Found what I wanted to do. Since the response's content type is `application/json` I've used `.json` with the response object, like: `resp_json = json.dumps(response.json(), sort_keys=True, indent=4)` and passed `resp_json` to the template.

Comment: Nice one! Glad you figured it out.