# Flask + JQuery can't read json response values, it sais "undefined"

Tags: jquery, python, json, ajax, flask

I have two similar JQuery ajax calls in my page that seems to behave differently:

```
$(".influence").click(function() {
    $(this).text(parseInt($(this).text()) + 1);
    var $state = $(this).parent();
    var faction = $("#faction").text();
    $.ajax({url: '/api/add_influence',
                data: {'state_id': parseInt($state.attr("stateid"))
                      ,'faction': faction
                    ,'game_id': $('#uid').text()},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(response) {
                    $(this).text(response['new_infl']);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            })
    $state.render_state();
    return false;
    });

$("#submit").click(function() {
    var faction = $("#faction").text();
    $.ajax({url: '/api/submit_move',
                data: {'faction': faction
                    ,'game_id': $('#uid').text()},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#status").text(response["player_status"]);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            })
    return false;
    });
```

..and this is the Flask code in my app:

```
@app.route('/api/add_influence', methods=['POST'])
def apply_command():
    ...blah blah blah...
    return json.dumps({'new_infl': state.influence[faction]})


@app.route('/api/submit_move', methods=['POST'])
def submit_move():
    ...blah blah blah...
    return json.dumps({'player_status': 'Your turn'})
```

The first works, in particular `response['new_infl']` is the value that I sended as a response.

The latter behave differently, if I log `response["player_status"]` it prints `undefined`, but if I log `response` it prints the correct JSON `{"player_status": "Your turn"}`

What am I missing here?

Comment: are you sure that response is treated as object and not as string? Have you tried to call jQuery.parseJSON() ?

Comment: Instead of using `$.ajax()` you should use `$.getJSON()`, that'll handle the JSON parsing and hand you a nice JSON object instead of a jqXHR object.

Comment: [You should use `jsonify` instead of `json.dumps`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907596/json-dumps-vs-flask-jsonify).

Comment: @dirn `jsonify` solved the problem, thanks, but my question remains, why the two different behaviors?

Comment: When you return the result of `json.dumps`, you are returning a string. Your response will have a content type of `text/html`. In order for JavaScript to implicitly handle it as JSON, it needs a return type of `application/json`. I'm not sure why it ever worked for you.