# NameError: global name 'HttpResponse' is not defined

Tags: python, json, flask

This is my Python code:

```
@app.route("/getdata", methods=['GET'])
def get_User():
myuser= User 
myuser=User.query.all()
    if myuser =="":
        return 404
    return HttpResponse(myuser, content_type="application/json")
```

I am trying to make sure the data I send is in JSON format. but it is giving me an error. Can I not use HttpResponse in Flask?

Answer (score 2):

Use `flask.Response`:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Response

`return flask.Response(myuser, content_type="application/json")`

If `myuser` is not actually JSON, which appears to be the case for you, you can:

```
import json 
myuser = json.dumps([u.as_dict() for u in User.query.all()])
```

You might also consider `jsonify` which is built into flask:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13172658/4225229

Comment: it is giving me an error "TypeError: Expected bytes"

Comment: You'll need to convert `myuser` to JSON per my answer update