# How can I specify encoding of string that comes from server side?

Tags: javascript, flask, unicode, encoding

I am relatively new to web development and even less familiar when it comes to the front end side. I've got a problem regarding an encoding issue.

- environment: python 2.7, Flask

I am sending json data to a server like this.

```
@app.route("/test")
def test():
    data = json.dumps({"name": "홍길동", "id": "gildong1"}, ensure_ascii=False)
    return render_template("testpage.html", data=data)
```

I printed out the data on the server side and it prints Korean characters just fine.

But whenever I receive the data in javascript like this:

```
var t_data = JSON.parse({{data}});
```

The result in the console is like this:

```
var t_data = JSON.parse({&#34;name&#34;: &#34;홍길동&#34;, &#34;id&#34;: &#34;gildong1&#34;});
```

**Update**

I am suspicious of the content-type header. When I inspected it through the debugger, I found that the **Content-Type** header is **u'text/html'**.
So I tried to change my code like this, but it still prints unicode:

```
@app.route("/test")
def test():
    data = json.dumps({"name":"홍길동", "id": "gildong1"}, ensure_ascii=False).encode("utf8")
    resp = make_response(render_template("TestPage.html", data=data))
    resp.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    return resp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the response in the server side to

convert your line

```
`data = json.dumps({"name": "홍길동", "id": "gildong1"}, ensure_ascii=False)`
```

to

```
`data = json.dumps({"name": "홍길동", "id": "gildong1"}, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')`
```

OR

Handle this on the client side using regex to replace all occurrence of `&#34;` to `"`

```
var input = '{&#34;name&#34;: &#34;홍길동&#34;, &#34;id&#34;: &#34;gildong1&#34;}'
input = input.replace(/(&#34;)/g,'"');
console.log(input); // {"name": "홍길동", "id": "gildong1"}
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't there any default option in javascript on which encoding I can choose?

Comment: convert your line `data = json.dumps({"name": "홍길동", "id": "gildong1"}, ensure_ascii=False)` to `data = json.dumps({"name": "홍길동", "id": "gildong1"}, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')`

Comment: @KimHyungJune I have update the answer. You can do this in your server side while doing `json.dumps` call

Comment: Actually, I also tried your suggestion earlier but the result was same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `jsonify()` instead of `json.dumps()`?
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907596/json-dumps-vs-flask-jsonify) and this little piece of code

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, json
app = Flask(__name__)
data = json.dumps({"name":"홍길동", "id": "gildong1"})
with app.app_context():
  data2 = jsonify(name="홍길동", id= "gildong1")
print (data)
print(data2.get_json())
# output
# {"id": "gildong1", "name": "\ud64d\uae38\ub3d9"}
# {'id': 'gildong1', 'name': '홍길동'}
```