# Convert JSON Dictionary to JSON Array in python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have JSON dictionary something like this:

```
{'foo': 3, 'bar': 1}
```

and i want it in JSON array form:

```
[ { "key": "foo", "value": 3 }, { "key": "bar", "value": 1 }]
```

What should I do?

Comment: what did you do so fat? in any case just create an array, append the items and when you finished based on the use you can jsonify() or json.dumps(): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907596/json-dumps-vs-flask-jsonify

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to iterate over keys and values for this dictionary and then assign the necessary keys in the new dictionary.

```
import json

input_dict = {'foo': 3, 'bar': 1}
result = []

for k, v in input_dict.items():
    result.append({'key': k, 'value': v})

print(json.dumps(result))
```

And the result:

```
[{'value': 3, 'key': 'foo'}, {'value': 1, 'key': 'bar'}]
```

Answer (score 4):

This could be handled with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
import json
json_dict = {'foo': 3, 'bar': 1}
json_array = [ {'key' : k, 'value' : json_dict[k]} for k in json_dict]
print(json.dumps(json_array))
```

output:

> [{"key": "foo", "value": 3}, {"key": "bar", "value": 1}]

Answer (score 1):

Try this (Python 2.7 and above):

```
json_dict = {'foo': 3, 'bar': 1}  # your original dictionary;
json_array = []  # an array to store key-value pairs;

# Loop through the keys and values of the original dictionary:
for key, value in json_dict.items():
    # Append a new dictionaty separating keys and values from the original dictionary to the array:
    json_array.append({'key': key, 'value': value})
```

One-liner that does the same thing:

```
json_array = [{'key': key, 'value': value} for key, value in {'foo': 3, 'bar': 1}.items()]
```

Hope this helps!