# I am struggling to get value by key from the jsonify object in python-flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to get records from mysql, if records found then adding success status with the mysql records and return by `jsonify` function, On the other side i am getting response and then check whether the status is success or not.

This is my response format

```
 [ { "SQL_STATUS": true }, { "id": "126","etc":"etc"} ]
```

i need to check whether the SQL_STATUS is `true` or `false`, so i tried the below method

```
      response.SQL_STATUS
```

but got the below error

```
      AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'SQL_STATUS'
```

These are my code

```
 def Details(self,request):

    res = self.db.SelectByConditionModel(request,self.model)


    if res.SQL_STATUS == True:
        response_data = SuccessResponse('','Success')
    else:
        response_data = ErrorResponse(res,"Database Error")

    return response_data
```

this is the fundtion where i am doing select operation

```
 @staticmethod
def SelectByConditionModel(request,model):

    try:

        where_condition  = []

        for key in request:
            where_condition.append(key+"='"+conn.escape_string(str(request[key]))+"'")


        where_condition_str = ', '.join(where_condition)

        sql = ''' SELECT * from %s WHERE %s ''' %(model.TABLE, where_condition_str)


        cursor.execute(sql)
        row_headers=[x[0] for x in cursor.description]
        conn.commit()
        data = cursor.fetchall()

        json_data=[]

        json_data.append({"SQL_STATUS" : True})

        for result in data:
            json_data.append(dict(zip(row_headers,result)))


        return jsonify(json_data)

    except Exception as e:

        return str(e)
```

i need to check SQL_STATUS is true or false, please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `json_data` is a `list`. `list`s are accessed by indexing, not through attributes.

```
json_data[0]['SQL_STATUS']
```

This would give you what you want. But you're turning it into a string before returning - so you'll need to turn it back into an object to access it like that.

```
@staticmethod
def SelectByConditionModel(request,model):
    try:
        where_condition  = []
        for key in request:
          where_condition.append(key+"='"+conn.escape_string(str(request[key]))+"'")
        where_condition_str = ', '.join(where_condition)
        sql = ''' SELECT * from %s WHERE %s ''' %(model.TABLE, where_condition_str)
        cursor.execute(sql)
        row_headers=[x[0] for x in cursor.description]
        conn.commit()
        data = cursor.fetchall()

        json_data=[]

        for result in data:
            json_data.append(dict(zip(row_headers,result)))

        return True, jsonify(json_data)

    except Exception as e:

        return False, str(e)
```

Here I'm returning `SQL_STATUS` separately from the method. Instead of adding it to the response. You can then do:

```
def Details(self,request):
    sql_status, res = self.db.SelectByConditionModel(request,self.model)
    if sql_status:
        response_data = SuccessResponse('','Success')
    else:
        response_data = ErrorResponse(res, "Database Error")
    return response_data
```

Comment: thank you, it's working now. but it's throw an error while framing response `TypeError: <Response 1021 bytes [200 OK]> is not JSON serializable`

Comment: here is the method, i wrote for framing response for the API call `def SuccessResponse(data,message): return json.dumps({'status':'success','data':data,'message':message,'status_code':200}), 200, {'ContentType':'application/json'}`

Comment: when i put the `res` to this method, i got this error `response_data = SuccessResponse(res,'Success')` if i use empty string instead, there is no error `response_data = SuccessResponse("",'Success')`

Comment: Yeah this is the reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907596/json-dumps-vs-flask-jsonify

Comment: You don't need to do `json.dumps` if you've used `jsonify` already.

Comment: ok, i have changed to make_response `return make_response(jsonify({'status':'success','data':data,'message':message,'status_code':200}),200)` but now also having same pblm, is there any response size restriction in python-flask?

Comment: I don't think you've understood how `jsonify` works. It's returning a proper response object already.